# “Excel found unreadable content in filenae.xls" error

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

am trying to download a excel but when i open i get the error:

“Excel found unreadable content in filenae.xls"

any ideas why. is it in the database?

link http://adhd.anytimeafter9.co.uk/_admin/adminworker.aspx?action=downloadstories&dest=story

thanks

Comment: The header is correct for an office document but there is no valid data beyond that. It was corrupted during download or not correctly created in the first place.

Comment: yeah am thinking that its been corrupted, its a site where i allow people to add stories, so am thinking when they add " or ' it may cause a problem, any ideas what it can be...

Comment: This question as it stands is not about programming... it has nothing to do with C# or SQL so i am not sure why it was tagged with it

Comment: because am making this site in .net and using sql to get the data...

Comment: the problem is something in the database which i cant open

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a bad file...

If you have access to the original this may help

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8abedda-619e-4f9d-97a5-fba2fcacd8c2/excel-found-unreadable-content-in-filenamexls-do-you-want-to-recover-the-contents-of-this?forum=excel

Comment: Is that your answer? Really?

Comment: Ok Soner, Im listening. Give me a better answer with the information he provided. It is a link to a direct excel document with no information about what the document is.

Comment: can it be because of character? because on the database it has "" etc

Comment: rule of thumb: is bad questions if cant be improved via editing should be closed and deleted not answered.